# How to read contents of a file into two separate char buffers using a while loop?

Tags: c, system-calls, uniq

First and foremost, I'm trying to simulate the 'uniq' Linux command in C, using only system calls. What I'm currently trying to do is read lines from a text file into two different char buffers, namely `char *buffer1` and `char *buffer2`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    char *buffer1 = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    char *buffer2 = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof(char));

    // read the first line into buffer1 using read() sys call
    int i = 0;
    while (read(input_fd, &buffer1[i], 1) == 1) 
    {
        if (buffer1[i] == '\n')
        {
            buffer1[i] = '\0';
            write(output_fd, buffer1, i);
            break;
        } 
        else
        {
            i++;

            if (i > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                perror("ERROR: Line is longer than the allocated buffer.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    // read the second line into buffer2
    int j = 0;
    char *temp_ptr;
    while(read(input_fd, &buffer2[j], 1) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer2[j] == '\n')
        {
            buffer2[j] = '\0';

            while (buffer2 != NULL)
            {
                if (strcmp(buffer1, buffer2) != 0)
                {
                    write(output_fd, buffer2, j);
                }

                j = 0;
               // after this if-statement, read in another line of text and compare it
               // to the string in buffer2 
                temp_ptr = buffer2;

                if (temp_ptr == buffer2) 
                {
                    temp_ptr = buffer1;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp_ptr = buffer2;
                }
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            j++;

            if (j > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                perror("ERROR: Line is longer than the allocated buffer.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Could this be done using only one while-loop? Once more, I'd like to stress the fact that I can only use system calls. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Before `i++;` why not `buffer2[i] = buffer1[i];`? and `buffer2[i] = '\0';` following `buffer1[i] = '\0';`?? Or just fill `buffer1` and then `memcpy (buffer2, buffer1, i * sizeof *buffer1);` (would require `string.h`, so that wouldn't meet the constraints, but the first method would.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What would the while-loop condition look like? Could you elaborate more on what `buffer2[i] = buffer1[i]` is supposed to do? For your second suggestion, are you saying I should read all the lines of the file into buffer1?

Comment: Don't change anything, just add `buffer2[i] = buffer1[i];` above `i++;` and then add `buffer2[i] = '\0';` immediately after `buffer1[i] = '\0';`. Then `buffer1` and `buffer2` will hold exactly the same contents after the first `while()` loop exits. (double check you have your `i++;` in the right place...

Comment: It's much more efficient to replace the single-char reads with block reads (i.e. read the whole buffer, then work in memory)

Comment: @tofro So what you're saying is I should merely create one while-loop, read the whole file into a single buffer, and then add each line into the appropriate buffer? How can I read multiple bytes at once? Is it something like: read(fd, &buffer, 20)?

Comment: You allocated `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` for the buffer - That is what you should read. And yes, the last argument to `read` is the amount of bytes you want.

Comment: regarding: `char *buffer1 = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof(char));` and `char *buffer2 = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof(char));`  1) checking for the success/fail of the calls to `malloc()` should be done immediately, and both calls should be checked, not just the second call.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C language as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: regarding: `while (read(input_fd, &buffer1[i], 1) == 1) 
    {
        if (buffer1[i] == '\n')
        {
            buffer1[i] = '\0';
            write(output_fd, buffer1, i);`  this code reads a single character, However; it writes out the number of characters as indicated in the variable `i`

Comment: rfegarding: `temp_ptr = buffer2;

                if (temp_ptr == buffer2)`  this `if()` statement will ALWAYS be TRUE

Comment: regarding: *I'm trying to simulate the 'uniq' Linux command in C, using only system calls.*  The posted code does not contain any system calls.  A system call starts with: `syscall()`  Perhaps you meant to only use low level C functions

Comment: the posted code fails to check for EOF.  I.E. when the call to `read()` returns 0.  the posted code fails to check if an I/O error occurred (returns -1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured it out:

```
// read the first line into buffer1 using read() sys call
    int i = 0;
    
    while (read(input_fd, &buffer1[i], 1) != 0) 
    {
        if (buffer1[i] == '\n')
        {
            buffer1[i] = '\0';
            write(output_fd, buffer1, i);
            
            i = 0;
            break;
        } 
        else
        {
            i++;
            if (i > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                perror("ERROR: Line is longer than the allocated buffer.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    int j = 0;
    ssize_t nr;
    while (read(input_fd, &buffer2[j], 1) != 0)
    {
        if (buffer2[j] == '\n')
        {
            buffer2[j] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(buffer1, buffer2) != 0)
            {
                write(output_fd, buffer2, j);
                if (nr == -1) {
                    perror("ERROR.\n");
                }
            }
            
            j = 0;
            char *current_ptr = buffer2;
            if (current_ptr == buffer2)
            {
                current_ptr = buffer1;
            } 
            else
            {
                current_ptr = buffer2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            if (j > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                perror("ERROR: Line is longer than the allocated buffer.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this answer still fails to check for an I/O error event